# Receiving error while displaying images loaded from device storage

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

A while ago I wrote a function that took a photo with the camera phone, saved it to the device's storage and showed the photos that were already taken on a page. The function was almost entirely based on [this](https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-image-upload-storage/) great example and worked perfectly.

To display the images on the page I use this function inside a ng-container:
`<ng-container *ngFor = "let img of images; index as pos" text-wrap>`

Now I'm writing a new version of the app with some functionality identical to the old one, including the one I mentioned. But now when this function of displaying images on the page is triggered I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

The maddening part is that the code involving this function is 100% the same as the previous one, which is working perfectly. Another thing, in the console I can see that the images were already loaded before the error was triggered, which makes the error even stranger because the `images` array is neither undefined nor null at the time the error is generated.

My code:

```js
const STORAGE_KEY = 'my_images';

export class MyPage implements OnInit {
    images = [];

    constructor(
        private file: File,
        private storage: Storage,
        private platform: Platform,
    )

    ngOnInit() {
        // When platform is ready, load stored images
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.loadStoredImages();
        });
    }

    loadStoredImages() {
        this.storage.get(STORAGE_KEY).then(images => {
            if (images) {
                let arr = JSON.parse(images);
                this.images = [];
                console.log(arr);

                // Populate local 'images' array with stored data
                for (let img of arr) {
                    let filePath = this.file.dataDirectory + img.name;
                    this.images.push({ name: img.name, filePath: filePath});
                }
                console.log(this.images);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you already verified that the first time you invoke the function, the FILE variable is not empty?

Comment: When `*ngFor = "let img of images; index as pos"` is fired, which is the function triggering the error, the `images` array is already populated. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: no, i am talking about the php upload file side...

Comment: As you can see by the title of the question, the function is independent of any interaction with the database. The data is already stored in device storage.

Comment: So you can't see any image as the error appears... do you have the last version of ionic?, are you having the updated plugins??, do you have updated npm?, oh other question important: in some time have you tried a similar version of this example and worked fine??, (in the recent days)

Comment: Latest version of Ionic, npm and all the cordova plugins. I just built (2h ago) the previous app with the same function, same framework and plugins versions, and is working as expected, with the images showing normally in the page. I can't think of any external factors that may be causing this.

Comment: i can think in 1 probably external issue, one is may be the default storage is now set to 'external' for some reason, so the function that is getting the images is returning nothing... other possibility is probably you have a typo??, i have looked at your link, and the resolveLocalFilesystemUrl as you see is typed wrong, if you have copied this directly of the actual ionic4 example you have a typo.

Comment: The fist one can't be because I'm receiving the images correctly from the device's storage. As you can see in the code I posted, inside the `loadStoredImages()`, I log the retrieved array from storage and later the populated `images` array.  Both are populated before the `*ngFor` function. The `resolveLocalFilesystemUrl()` function is used for upload images to a database in the link I posted and as I already said this function does not have this implemented, it works only with device storage.

Comment: i think the problem is that when you are using JSON.parse(images), some special characters are not escaped correctly, this causes the error, so have you tried first (before saving the images in to the storage, to treat them??), other way to display an images is displaying it in base64, so, try to remove first the actual images located in storage and reset new images using the example below.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the JSON parsing, if there were any problems I would get a related error as it already happened before. As I say, I can see the logged data from `images` array and I can see that the data is correct. I going to try your suggestions, I really appreciate all the help and effort you are providing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this case is the "text-wrap" attribute in the `<ng-container>` element.
As @rapropos mentioned in [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-error-while-displaying-images-loaded-from-device-storage/174355/6) post:

> ng-container doesn’t actually turn into a DOM element, so only
>   structural directives can be applied to it. The presence of text-wrap
>   is pulling in the CssUtilsDeprecations directive, which is not
>   structural and therefore assumes that it is sitting atop a DOM
>   element. It isn’t, so blammo.

Answer (score 0):

when getting the image in then(), you can addapt something like:

```
this.imagePicker.getPictures(options).then((results) => {

  for(let i = 0; i < results.length; i++){

    let filename = results[i].substring(results[i].lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    let path = results[i].substring(0, results[i].lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    this.file.readAsDataURL(path, filename).then((base64string)=>{

      this.image_data[i] = base64string;

    });

  }

});
```

i don't know if you get the images with the gallery, but this have worked for me, when i tried to make this work without using resolveLocalFileSystemUrl and using the device filepath seems not working...

Comment: If you like to use imagePicker (if you are not using it), this is the documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/image-picker, but this plugin has a heavy problem :(

Comment: Ah other thing: i think the function resolveLocalFileSystemUrl can help, resolveLocalFileSystemUrl is not only aplicable to send images to the php file (file which you are not implementing)... this resolveLocalFileSystemUrl as i know 'translates the current url' to the 'real url' of the located file in the system, so i think is neccessary, this because in some devices the: url 'file:///some-route/etc/' apparently is not a valid route of your phone the same for: 'file://some-route/etc/', so this can be recongnized as null in the img tag, but i'm not sure can be this...

Comment: Note: isn't neccessary to use resolveLocalFileSystemUrl if you are storing images in base64, but i think is neccessary doing it if you are using an img url from your phone (i have tried time ago doing it this way (using the system filepath, but not worked), so i decided to use in that time, base64 images instead the system URL), and worked perfectly.

Comment: Problem solved in another way, but I really appreciate your effort! Thank you very much for all your help!